# Call Java method taking String argument from C

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have Java method taking one `java.lang.String` argument. When I call it from C, I always get SIGSEGV when calling `NewStringUTF`.

How can I call the Java method with `char *` string?

```java
// Java
void doSomething(String str) { … }
```

```c
// C
void Java_some_very_long_function_name(JNIEnv *env, jobject thi)
{
    jclass clas = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, thi);
    jmethodID method = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clas, "doSomething", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    jstring str = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, strdup("My String")); // Segfaults here

    // TODO Call the method
}
```

It is happening **after** the `NewStringUTF` executes, not during `NewStringUTF` call.

```
art::FaultManager::HandleFault(int, siginfo*, void*) 0x00000000eae9efa4
art::art_fault_handler(int, siginfo*, void*) (.llvm.2308358812779254744) 0x00000000eae9eccb
___lldb_unnamed_symbol25$$app_process32 0x000000005c58cfe1
___lldb_unnamed_symbol2$$libc.so 0x00000000edd18180
art::Thread::DecodeJObject(_jobject*) const 0x00000000eb244c3f
<unknown> 0x00000000ec29f05d
<unknown> 0x000000005c58b000
Java_very_long_name foo.c:761
[…]
```

Comment: Can you post the SEGFAULT stacktrace? This sounds like a C problem and you should be able to spot the problem in the stacktrace and debug using the usual methods for C.

Comment: @Daniel Added stacktrace.

Comment: So NewStringUTF is not the problem? Which lime does it crash? What code do you have after the NewStringUTF call?

Comment: The example above is a bit simplified. I have function called from Java that calls the method creating the string. The debugger shows it on the line where is this method *called* so it must be just few instructions after execution of `NewStringUTF`.

Comment: Where is your `native void ...` function declaration in Java?  Also, from what you've posted you're not checking **any** of your JNI calls for errors or exceptions.  Continuing to call JNI functions with invalid values or with a pending exception can and does often result in abnormal termination of the JVM.

Comment: Show the rest of the function, then

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the segfault is caused by debugger. When I don't stop execution in the native method (using breakpoint), it runs without any problems.